# Drilldown search with Search API and Facets

Tags: entities, search

I have a type 'projects' referencing two other types ('kustomer','products') via entity reference.
Now I want to implement a drilldown search.
I therefore use search API with facete api. I build a index and a view for Type 'project'. The filtering works well on this view. I have facetes for types 'customer' and 'product' and can filter.

The target is a workflow where you start at a list of 'products'. When you select one you will get a list of 'customers' where a 'project' exists that contains that 'product'. After that you select a 'customer' and you get a List of all 'project's having that 'product' and 'customer' preselected as facetes.

Can someone point out a module or configuration that does that?
Thanks in advance
Clemens

Answer (score 0):

I use CER,  "Corresponding Entity References" to achieve similar results, but not with Search_API.. for that, I just tell the search-page to render the "teaser", and modify the teaser display to include the entity_reference list of associated entities as links, that way, if you search for a "Kustomer", it will show you a list of Kustomers and each project will also appear as a list of links underneath the title, or visaversa, you can also use Facets to filter by taxonomy etc.. handy!